# Atmega328p external interrupt to toggle mode

Tags: toggle, interrupt, interrupt-handling, led

I am working on a personal project that involves me pushing a button which allows me to switch through 2 modes. I have the following code. I have my button hardware debugged[Hardware debug Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB0JO.png)

So far what happens is when I power the MCU on initially the LED is on. When I push the button the LED goes out. When I press the button again the LED stays off until I press it over and over. At random intervals the LED will toggle.

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL // 16 MHz clock speed
#endif


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define SECUR    PD2     //Mode button
#define DISAM    PD3     //Mode LED

volatile uint8_t toggle0 = 1;


ISR(INT0_vect)
{
if (toggle0){
    toggle0=0;
}
else{
    toggle0=1;
}
}

int main(void)

{


DDRD |= (1<<3);     // configure PORTD2 as input
DDRD &= ~(1<<2);    // configure PORTD3 as output

EICRA |= (1 << ISC00)|(1 << ISC10);    // set INT0 to trigger on       Rising     edge
EIMSK |= (1 << INT0);                 // Turns on INT0
sei();                               // turn on interrupts

sei();               // Enable global interrupts

while (1)

{
    if(toggle0)
    {
        PORTD |= (1<<PD3);   // Mode LED off
    }
        else
        {
        PORTD &= ~(1<<PD3);   //Mode LED on
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1k Ohm * 0.1µF ~ 100µs. Might be too short for effective debouncing. Try a bigger cap and/or bigger resistors.

Comment: Thank you JimmyB I will try it with a 10k resistor and a 10UF cap to have a ~100ms